# file upload like yahoo mail file attachement in php?

Tags: php

how to develop an application for file upload like yahoo  mail file attachement in php.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of good tutorials on the topic:

- [Tizag: PHP Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)
- [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)
- [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)
- [PHP and Flash uploader](http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx)

In the future though, try searching for these things on [Google](http://www.google.com), [Bing](http://www.bing.com) or [Yahoo](http://www.yahoo.com) before asking here.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to recreate it or just know how to use `YUI.uploader`?

In the latter case, check

- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/
- http://thecodecentral.com/2007/09/04/asynchronous-file-upload-yuis-approach
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/asynchronous-file-upload-with-yui